# Ruby on rails: Bases de datos secundarias no conectan en producción

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Tengo una aplicación RoR que utiliza dos bases de datos simultaneas. De ellas, una es fija y la otra cambia de forma dinámica según el proyecto en el que se está trabajando.

Dispongo de ficheros .yml con la configuración de cada una, de modo que las bases de datos dinámicas van cambiando su conexión dependiendo del fichero .yml que le indique el programa durante su ejecución.

La base de datos que no da problemas es la "nativa" de ruby, configurada en el archivo database.yml

```
  default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 30 } %>
  encoding: unicode
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  timeout: 2400
  port: 5432

development:
  <<: *default
  host: xx.xx.xx.xx
  database: development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: development

production:
  <<: *default
  host: xx.xx.xx.xx
  database: production
```

Por otro lado, un ejemplo de uno de los ficheros que no funciona en producción es el siguiente:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 30 } %>
  timeout: 240000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/PROJECT1/xxx.db
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/xxx.db
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/PROJECT1/xxx.db
```

.

```
 default: &default
      adapter: postgresql
      pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 30 } %>
      encoding: unicode
      username: xxx
      password: xxx
      timeout: 240
      host: 172.xx.xx.xx
      port: 1111

    development:
      <<: *default
      database: xxxx

    test:
      <<: *default
      database: test

    production:
      <<: *default
      database: xxxx
```

Este último puede contener configuración para sqlite3 o para postgres indiferentemente, funciona correctamente en development. Dudo mucho que el error pueda encontrarse ahí, pero los incluyo para que se comprenda mejor.

Por otra parte, la conexión a la base de datos es "hibrida", en el sentido que tengo unas 40 tablas en la base de datos fija y unas 4 o 5 que varían según el proyecto seleccionado, ya que pertenecen a bases de datos de aplicaciones externas.

Estas conexiones se realizan de la siguiente forma:

```
class AuxDbBase < ActiveRecord::Base  
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

El código anterior hereda de AR pero me sirve para crear una conexión auxiliar para determinadas tablas como sigue:

Modelo "tabla":

```
class Tabla< AuxDbBase
    self.table_name ="tabla"
end
```

Conexión dinámica:

```
connection_db_params = YAML::load(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join("config/db_config", "#{project}.yml"))).result)[Rails.env]
Tabla.establish_connection connection_db_params
```

Esto ha estado meses funcionando en desarrollo, pero a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación con el entorno de producción, las tablas no conectan y se muestra el siguiente error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  no existe la relación «tabla»
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE type = 'xxx'
```

Por tanto tengo dos dudas principales:

1-¿Alguien conoce donde puede estar el origen del problema?

2-¿Qué puede cambiar a la hora de migrar de entorno para que esto esté sucediendo?

Y una cuestión secundaria: ¿Cómo podría mejorar esta forma de conectar las BBDDs? He estado leyendo acerca de multy-tenancy, que es como parece ser que se conoce a este cambio dinámico de tablas, pero no sé como mejorarlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Solución: finalmente di con el problema. En production environment existe la configuración "config.cache_classes = true". Ese parametro almacena las clases en caché y """no vuelve a leer el código""". Como yo cambio de forma dinámica la conexión, siempre se queda con la inicial y nunca más la vuelve a cambiar. Por ahora he puesto esa opción a false, pero es muy ineficiente e intentaré buscar una alternativa

Comment: ¿pero esto funcionaba en producción y ahora ya no? ¿esto te sale al correr migraciones o qué? si estás intentando ejecutar en producción por primera vez, quizás no has creado las tablas del todo ¿has verificado que las tablas efectivamente estén creadas en prod?

Comment: Está todo correctamente creado y verificado. Corre cuando el entorno es de desarrolo, pero no cuando es de producción. Añado, algo de lo que me he dado cuenta ahora, en la máquina local si funciona todo en producción, pero en el servidor no (windows con puma vs CentOS 7 con nginx+unicorn).
Además, la base de datos fija corre siempre, pero las secundarias no conectan en el server en producción (si en desarrollo en el mismo server). Puede ser algo de unicorn? no logro comprenderlo, estoy muy atascado  @AlterLagos

Comment: Dudo que sea algo relacionado con unicorn o nginx, ya que todo ese stack está entre las peticiones de usuarios que te llegan al servidor y tu aplicación rails. Tu problema lo tienes entre tu aplicación rails y tu db engine. Creo que tendrías que agregar a tu pregunta que es lo que estás haciendo para generar ese error, porque con la información que entregas no es posible saberlo. ¿estás usando capistrano para deployar o algún otro método?

Comment: No, el deploy lo hago simplemente arrancando un servicio que tira de unicorn. No sé que más información puede ser útil, realmente ese error da en un simple select. Puedo añadirte que: [Entorno development: funcionan siempre todo] - [Entorno producción: en local con windows funciona todo] [Entorno producción: servidores con CentOS: no funcionan los cambios de base de datos].

Comment: La app empieza conectada a la base de datos que tira de ActiveRecord::Base y cuando seleccionas un proyecto, cambia de base de datos. Pues ese cambio es el que no se está realizando, es decir, el Modelo.establish_connection no está funcionando en producción, no sé si esta funcionalidad está limitada en este entorno o que puede estar pasando

Comment: No se de que forma ayudarte, lo unico que se me ocurre es que trates de conectarte a la consola de rails en producción y trates de realizar la conexión manualmente para dilucidar que pueda estar pasando. Si la conexión se realiza, pero no existen las tablas, no veo otra razón que la creación de dichas tablas se haya realizado mal... o quizás no estás apuntando a las tablas correctas. Igual me entra una duda, si el fichero de config que no te funciona dice `adapter: sqlite3`, ¿por qué el error es `PG::UndefinedTable`, o sea, de postgresql?

Comment: Fallo mio, debí poner las dos versiones. Me conecto a la base de datos de una aplicación que está distribuida en varios servidores (trac), en uno de ellos se usa sqlite3 y en el resto postgres. La sqlite3 tengo que descargarla por scp para consultarla "localmente" hasta que hagamos la migración de ese servidor, que es muy antiguo y no podemos ni tocarlo ni instalar PGsql, por ello esa configuración con sqlite3. Cada proyecto tiene su archivo de configuración .yml para la bbdd. En tiempo de ejecución, cuando el usuario selecciona uno, yo hago la conexión con el archivo que se necesita.

Comment: Intentaré lo que me comentas, gracias!

Comment: @AlterLagos finalmente di con el problema. En production environment existe la configuración "config.cache_classes = true". Ese parametro almacena las clases en caché y """no vuelve a leer el código""". Como yo cambio de forma dinámica la conexión, siempre se queda con la inicial y nunca más la vuelve a cambiar. Por ahora he puesto esa opción a false, pero es muy ineficiente e intentaré buscar una alternativa. Gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Me alegro que encontraras la solución. Lo ideal sería que agregaras tu solución como respuesta a tu pregunta por si más adelante alguien tiene un problema similar al tuyo. Saludos

Comment: Me quedé pensando en lo que dijiste sobre `cache_classes` y como dices, no es una buena opción para producción. En guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html hay varias referencias a dicha configuración y puede que alguna de las que mencionan te sirva para lo que necesitas, yo creo que debe existir alguna forma para recargar dinámicamente solo las clases necesarias en vez de todo el entorno, lamentablemente nunca he trabajado con mutitenancy como para ayudarte ahí. Buena suerte

Comment: Lo revisaré. Te destaco un dato por si en el futuro te sirve: solo pasa con unicorn, con puma si se cambia correctamente aunque esté en producción y con cache_classes a true. Muchas gracias @AlterLagos